# Eloquent between two dates from database, Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a voucher or coupon table in the database. there is start_date and finish_date to determine the validity of the voucher or coupon. by obtaining the day, date, and time of the day then, if the validity period is still active the voucher or coupon can be used and if the validity period has expired the voucher or coupon can not be reused.
below is the source code I use to process vouchers or coupons, but it does not work very well.
is there anybody who can help me for this problem?
thank you

```
public function coupon()
{
    $c = Input::get('coupon');
    $date = Carbon::now();
    $check = StoreVoucher::whereRaw("code = '".$c."'")
    ->whereRaw("status = 1")
    ->whereRaw("start_date", ">=", $date)
    ->whereRaw("finish_date", "<=", $date)
    ->first();
}
```

Comment: What's error you are facing?

Comment: Why are you using `whereRaw()` instead of `where()`? `whereRaw("code = '".$c."'")` is extremely insecure because it's vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan nothing is error, just my loading process takes a long time

Comment: If your website is too slow, this simple query is definitely not the reason.

Comment: what is the data type of your start_date and finsh_date in your migration?

Comment: @TonzFale start_date and finsh_date, i use date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function coupon() {    
    return StoreVoucher::where('code', Input::get('coupon'))
                         ->where('status', '1')
                         ->where('start_date', '>=', Carbon::now())
                         ->where('finish_date', '<=', Carbon::now())
                         ->first();
}
```

Add this to your `StoreVoucher` model:

```
protected $dates = ['start_date', 'finish_date'];
```

Comment: thanks for the answers you provide, but the code is still wrong, no error message just the process of loading when the button on click takes a long time

Comment: I've added protected $dates = ["start_date", "finish_date", "deleted_at"]; but the error appears Class 'Carbon' not found

Comment: can you add the column structure of the 2 fields, the lines of code when you created the migration will do e.g. `$table->dateTime('start_date')` as well as an example record in the database

Comment: @AgusSuparman also at the top after the namespace declaration add `use Carbon\Carbon;`

Answer (score 1):

```
public function coupon()
{
    $c = Input::get('coupon');
    $date = Carbon::now();
    $check = StoreVoucher::where("code",$c)
    ->whereStatus(1)
    ->whereDate("start_date", ">=", $date)
    ->whereDate("finish_date", "<=", $date)
    ->first();
}
```

try this out

Comment: try formatting the date `$date->format('Y-m-d')` as the way to saved in the database

Answer (score 0):

You are using whereRaw but in a wrong way.

```
public function coupon()
{
    $c = Input::get('coupon');
    $date = Carbon::now();
    $check = StoreVoucher::whereRaw("code = '".$c."'")
    ->whereRaw("status = 1")
    ->whereRaw("start_date >= '$date'")
    ->whereRaw("finish_date <= '$date'")
    ->first()
}
```

WhereRaw() method takes condition as a string.

Comment: thanks for the answers you provide, but the code is still wrong, no error message just the process of loading when the button on click takes a long time

Comment: I've added protected $dates = ["start_date", "finish_date", "deleted_at"];
but the error appears Class 'Carbon' not found